# Ibm cm development java api, item type's auto-linking property

Tags: content-management-system

I am developing a new application for ibm db2 content manager, using java api. Just like in ibm cm system administration client does, I am trying to copy an existing item type's properties to a new item type by java coding.

I will only change item type's name and definition. All remaning property will be copied as is; like attributes, retention policy, auto linking, collection names..

Does any one know how to get existing item type's 'auto-linking' property and set it to new item type?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I used the below way to get and set auto-link property.

---

```
boolean autoLinkBol = source_itemType.getAutoLinkEnable();
new_itemType.setAutoLinkEnable(autoLinkBol);
dkCollection coll =  source_itemType.getAutoLinkRule();   
dkIterator iter = coll.createIterator(); // Create an iterator to iterate 
while(iter.more()){ // while there are still items in the list, continue
   DKAutoLinkDefICM autoLinkDef = (DKAutoLinkDefICM) iter.next();
   DKAutoLinkDefICM autoLinkDef_new =  new DKAutoLinkDefICM();
   autoLinkDef_new.setLinkType(autoLinkDef.get`enter code here`LinkType());
   autoLinkDef_new.setSourceEntityName(autoLinkDef.getSourceEntityName());
   autoLinkDef_new.setAttributeId(autoLinkDef.getAttributeId());
   autoLinkDef_new.setTargetEntityName("XXX_05");
   new_itemType.addAutoLinkRule(autoLinkDef_new);
}
```